# Neo4j How to add multiple relationships with property filter of each relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

`MATCH (me)-[post_rel_source:FOLLOWS_TEAM|:FOLLOWS|:FOLLOWS_EVENT*0..1]->(user)`

In this case how can I check different 'status' of all 3 relations?
FOLLOWS_TEAM has accepted:1
FOLLOWS has accepted:1
FOLLOWS_EVENT dont have any status.

If I add like following, its not working for 'FOLLOWS_EVENT'

```
[post_rel_source:FOLLOWS_TEAM|:FOLLOWS|:EVENTS_OF_ORG*0..1{accepted:1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

This snippet should work:

```
...
MATCH (me)-[r:FOLLOWS_TEAM|:FOLLOWS|:FOLLOWS_EVENT*0..1]->(user)
WHERE
  SIZE(r) = 0 OR
  TYPE(r[0]) = 'FOLLOWS_EVENT' OR
  r[0].accepted = 1
...
```

Note: since your relationship pattern allows for a 0-length path (i.e., a path where `me` and `user` are the same node, and there is no matching relationship between them), the `SIZE(r) = 0` test detects and accepts that case (which is presumably what you wanted).

Comment: Its showing error -
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was List<Relationship> (line 2, column 34 (offset: 198))
WHERE TYPE(r)='FOLLOWS_EVENT'